# Android RecyclerView ViewHolder OnClickListener only working when edge of item is clicked

Tags: android, view

This is not my first time implementing an adapter for a RecyclerView so I don't understand this issue.

I have the recycler view populating with items using a custom list item
I also have the Viewholder itemView.setOnClickListener set and when I click the item, it doesn't register the click.

But, when I click a little above the text on the item, it registers the click... Maybe something to do with my custom item layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Plan ID:" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Username:" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Timestamp:" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/plan_id_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/username_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timestamp_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/options"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_40"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_small"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final TextView timestamp_tv = v.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_tv);
    switch (form_name) {
        case "daily_worksheet":
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("timestamp", timestamp_tv.getText().toString());
            new LoadActivityTask((Activity) context, new Intent(context, DailyWorksheet_View.class), "Daily Worksheet Form", bundle).execute();
            break;

        default:break;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView plan_id, username, timestamp;
    private ImageView options;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(ReceiptAdapter.this);
        plan_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plan_id_tv);
        username =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_tv);
        timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_tv);
        options = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code of adapter `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: you will do well by using ConstraintLayout instead of all those nested LinearLayouts, it's a really bad practice. Plus it may solve your clicking issues. You can read more about it here https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete android:clickable="true" in the first LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is because you are setting the OnClickListener on the Root of your layout, and your CardView which is basically the main background of your layout is not clickable, so the only space which affect the OnClicklistener is the small margin of the CardView.

I think you should set the OnClicklistener on the Cardview (and set as clickable).

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView).setOnClickListener(ReceiptAdapter.this);
```